# InputDecoration suffix icon is no aligned properly for bigger fonts

Tags: flutter, textfield

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(80.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: size.height * 0.06,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            size: size.height * 0.06,
                          ),
                          suffixIcon:IconButton(
                              onPressed: ()=> print('pressed'),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                size: size.height * 0.06,
                              ),
                              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[300],
                            ),
                          hintText: 'Game',
                          fillColor: Colors.black87,
                          filled: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code shows the the suffix X icon shifted to bottom right corner while using bigger font size where as the prefix icon is showing properly. Please refer below screenshot

[Screenshot in android pixel C emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8dth.png) 
Flutter 1.17.1 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision f7a6a7906b (5 weeks ago) • 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
Engine • revision 6bc433c6b6
Tools • Dart 2.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was because of the IconButton. Changing it to InkWell solved the issue.

```
 suffixIcon: InkWell(
             onTap: () => onTextClear(),
             child: Icon(
                     Icons.close,
                     size: Constants.screenHeight * 0.04,
                    ),
                   ),
```

Comment: Thanks renji, it work like a charm